# Предлог "-из"

Tags: грамотная-речь, орфография

Верен ли предлог в предложении для всех перечислений: «Бродяги почти исчезнут из дворов, улиц, вокзалов, брошенных ветхих домов, чердаков, подвалов, линий теплотрасс и т.д.»?

Answer (score 2):

**Из** домов,  подвалов, но **с** улиц, чердаков, вокзалов, линий. (Ср.: **в** домах, подвалах, но **на** улицах, чердаках, вокзалах, линиях). Слово дворы можно употребить с предлогами из, со (ср.: во дворах, на дворе).

Comment: В качестве небольшого пояснения: предлоги В, НА - синонимы, им соответствуют антонимичные пары ИЗ, С. Именно поэтому в дом -из дома, на крышу - с крыши.

Answer (score 0):

Вполне нормально звучит.